# C# & SQL Server : turn sql data into class module using DataContext

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012, datacontext, sql-server-2017-express

I may be going about this the hard way but I am wanting to gather 1 row from the SQL Server database (by `ID` column), and place those values inside an instance of my `class` (which is `chromeExtData`).

My class:

```
public class chromeExtData 
{
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string mname { get; set; }
    public string numsr { get; set; }
    public string sor { get; set; }
    public string pob { get; set; }
    public string birthday { get; set; }
    public string cstatus { get; set; }
    public string miscnumbers { get; set; }
    public List<string> transp { get; set; }
}
```

And my database layout:

```
---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+----------+---------+-------------+--------
ID | lname | fname | mname | numsr | sor | pob | birthday | cstatus | miscnumbers | transp
---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+----------+---------+-------------+--------
5  | Barker| Bob   | null  | aB342 | U76 | CA  | 5/25/1970| Active  | A123        | A,X,Y
```

And what I want to do is just pull that information into the object and vice-versa.

I found this code that I **think** does what I am wanting to do:

```
int ID = 5;

using (var dc = new DataContext())
{
    var people = dc.ExecuteQuery<chromeExtData>(@"SELECT * 
                                                  FROM [People]
                                                  WHERE [ID] = {0}", ID).ToList();
}
```

I'm not sure if the code above would place the found data values into the `chromeExtData` object or not? I've never used this `DataContext` before so I'm unsure if that's the correct way to go about what I want to do.

Comment: When in doubt you need to check the first-party documentation. Here is the documentation for ExecuteQuery<T>, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Linq_DataContext_ExecuteQuery__1_System_String_System_Object___

Comment: Additionally, did you TRY the code you posted? Just put it in and click F5. see what happens. If you have to add some breakpoints or Console.WriteLines or Debugger writes